# Identifying a PDE from an old notebook

Tags: partial-differential-equations

A friend of mine ran across the following PDE in some notes from an old friend of theirs:

$$
\theta \frac{d^2\theta}{dt^2} + \delta\frac{d\theta}{dt} + \frac{dL}{d\alpha}(\rho_1-\rho_2)\alpha = \frac{dR}{dB}S_2B\,.
$$
The $L$ here might be a different character, it's garbled in the writing.

I like a good math mystery so I did some poking around for it but couldn't find anything. They indicated it might have something to do with balancing things that wobble, possibly rockets. Any ideas?

Comment: Some thoughts: if $B=\beta$ then one could look at [Euler angles](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler_angles) which are often labelled $\alpha$, $\beta$, $\gamma$. The $\rho_1-\rho_2$ term and context reminds me of the [rigid body equations](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler%27s_equations_(rigid_body_dynamics))

Comment: Thanks I'll take a look!